# How to fix warning: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I'm working on a classification project, where I try out various types of models like logistic regression, decision trees etc, to see which model can most accurately predict if a patient is at risk for heart disease (given an existing data set of over 3600 rows).

I'm currently trying to work on my decision tree, and have plotted ROC curves to find the optimized values for tuning the max_depth and min_samples_split hyperparameters. However when I try to create my new model I get the warning:

> "UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0
> due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control
> this behavior."

I have already googled the warning, and semi understand why it's happening, but not how to fix it. I don't want to just get rid of the warning or ignore the values that weren't predicted. I want to actually fix the issue. From my understanding, it has something to do with how I processed my data. However, I'm not sure where I went wrong with my data processing.

I started off with doing a train-test split, then used StandardScaler like so:

```
#Let's split the data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


X = df.drop("TenYearCHD", axis = 1)
y = df["TenYearCHD"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 42)

#Let's scale our data
SS = StandardScaler()
X_train = SS.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = SS.transform(X_test)
```

I then created my initial decision tree, and received no warnings:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy")

#Fit our model and predict
dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)
dtc_pred = dtc.predict(X_test)
```

After looking at my ROC curve and AOC scores, I attempted to create another more optimized decision tree, **which is where I then received my warning**:

```
dtc3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", max_depth = 4, min_samples_split= .25)
dtc3.fit(X_train, y_train)
dtc3_pred = dtc3.predict(X_test)
```

Essentially i'm at a loss at what to do. Should I use a different method like StratifiedKFolds in addition to train-test split to process my data? Should I do something else entirely? Any help would be greatly appreciated.